# SyntasticCheck C++ header

Tags: plugin-syntastic

First, I'm **not** asking how to include includes in a syntastic check.  I already have:

```
let g:syntastic_c_check_header = 1
```

And when I run `:SyntasticCheck`, or save, a `.cpp` file, it also checks relevant includes if they are in `syntastic_c_include_dirs`.  It even opens an error location_list window in the buffer containing the `.hpp` if I then jump to it.

That's great, but what it won't do is check the header directly, whether I save it or use `:SyntasticCheck` in the `.hpp` buffer.

This means when working on template classes made only of an `.hpp`, I have to load some file that uses it and run the check from there; sometimes the easiest way to do this is to just create a dummy `.cpp` file with one line in it (`#include "foo.hpp"`).  But this is still stupid and annoying.

Is anyone aware of a way to get Syntastic to check a C++ header directly, without having to run a check on file which uses the header?

Comment: Have you tried setting `g:syntastic_cpp_check_header` to 1 instead of `g:syntastic_c_check_header`?

Comment: @lcd047 :/ I know that maybe qualifies this for "whoops, delete, ignore me..." but if you want to put it in an answer, please do.

Answer (score 1):

> But this is still stupid and annoying.

Or maybe that's just me.  I had not noticed there's separate but similar options for C and C++.

```
let g:syntastic_cpp_check_header
```

Does the trick.